# Odd and even extension (fourier series)

Tags: calculus, functions, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, even-and-odd-functions

How to expand $f(x)=x^2$ in the interval of $(0,\pi)$ to an odd and even function with the interval of $(-\pi,\pi)$?

I know that in even function $f(x)=f(-x)$ and for an odd function $f(-x)=-f(x)$
which in this case, for even:

$f(x)= x^2$ for $0$ to $\pi$

$f(x)=-x^2$ for $-\pi$ to $0$

For odd function:

$f(x)=x^2$ for $0$ to $\pi$

$f(x)=-(-x^2)=x^2$ for $-\pi$ to $0$

Is this correct? And how do you extend this function to become an odd function and how to extend this to become an even function? I don't understand how to do this expansion.

Comment: The only function that is both odd and even is the constant zero function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers are backwards.  $f(x)=x^2$ is even as $f(-x)=(-x)^2=x^2=f(x)$.  Intuitively, even means the graph is symmetric around the $y$ axis and $y=x^2$ is.  Then to extend it to an odd function, for which we will use $g$, when $x \gt 0$ we need $g(-x)=-g(x)=-(x^2)$

Comment: oh! Then how do you expand it into -pi to pi interval? I still didn't get how to do this

Comment: There is nothing about your $f$ that is restricted to $(0,\pi)$.  $f(x)=x^2$ is even over $(-\infty,\infty) and is still even if you restrict it to $(-\pi,\pi)$.  For an odd function you want $x^2$ when $x \gt 0$ and $-x^2$ when $x \lt 0$.  That also works over either interval.  Plot them and see what you get.

Comment: Okay Thanks a lot!